# find_or_create_by_name_and_location creating ActiveRecord duplicates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to rails (and coding in general) and am writing a small project using RSpec for testing.  I'm currently stuck on a Model test that should be pretty straightforward and I'm tearing my hair out.

I have a logfile to parse for errors.  Each error has a name (eg. `NoMethodError`) and a location (eg. `"app/controllers/public/profiles_controller.rb:46:in 'index'`) .  I have successfully parsed them from the log, and am now trying to write them to my `Errors` database using ActiveRecord.

I want each error/location combination to be recorded once only.  I am currently using this block in my model to do so:

```
#app/models/error.rb
Error.find_or_create_by_name_and_location(@name, @location) do |error|
error.first_seen  = (Time.now - 1.day)
error.last_seen   = Time.now  # These time objects are just filler for now
end
```

As far as I can make out, this should create a new entry in my `Errors` database *only* if there is not a pre-existing entry with the same name and location.  However, this is not the case.

I have created a sample log to run my tests on, which has two identical and one unique error/location pairs.  I want these to be recorded as 2 entries in `Errors`.  However, when I run my test the duplicates are not filtered out, so I end up with 3 entries.

I wrote a test to check the find_or_create_by_name_and_location method and it works fine:

```
#RSpec 
#spec/models/error_spec.rb
Error.find_or_create_by_name_and_location( "foo", "bar")
Error.find_or_create_by_name_and_location( "foo", "bar")
Error.should have(1).record
#Test passes
```

I've tried everything I can think of but I'm getting nowhere fast, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should add a validation to your model to enforce the uniqueness, regardless of whether the `find_or_create_by` method is working as you expect.

```
class Error << ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :location

end
```

This way there can only ever be one record with the same name and location.

Comment: Ah great, that's really useful, thank you - I should be able to use it as a workaround.  Still wish I knew why `find_or_create_by` isn't working as I expect...even my boss couldn't work it out, so I don't think it's just that I'm a total neophyte!

Comment: OK, now I'm totally stumped - it _still_ doesn't work.  Even with the model enforcing uniqueness as above, I end up with two duplicate entries.  The find_or_create_by code is in an `if` loop and there's no way I can think of that race conditions come into play (ie. the code verifies uniqueness of both errors first, _then_ writes).  Any ideas at all?

Comment: A while back I encountered a similar problem. The solution was to write it as two queries `unless instance = Model.find(); instance = Model.create(); end`. Not as pretty, but works.

Comment: Thanks again, another good suggestion...still can't get it working though!  I set up an unless loop as you suggested, but it still gives me duplicates: `unless instance =Error.find_by_error_name_and_location(@name, @location); instance = Error.create(:error_name => @name, :location => @location ); end`.  Absolutely no idea what I have done wrong, most frustrating!  Going to try a unique index instead, which will impact performance but hopefully at least function.  Thanks very much for your help!  Can't upmark until I get more rep but I will come back and do it later, if I ever make it to 15 :)